# Pass a dynamic URL field into a link using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, onload, var

I am trying to parse the email ("test@test.com") from the url and insert it together with an identifier to the popupwidget url.

The end result should be "showPopupWidget('https://website.com?utm_campaign=test@test.com')".

Unfortunately, I cannot seem to get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```js
//<![CDATA[
window.onload=function(){
url = "https://url.com/abc?email=test@test.com";
var paramId = new URL(url).searchParams.get("email");

var frameElement = document.getElementById("calendlyid");
frameElement.src = "https://webite.com" + "?utm_campaign=" +paramId;


}//]]>
```

```html
<h2 class="subtitle">
<a id="calendlyid" href="" onclick="iAmAttilasEvent(); Calendly.showPopupWidget('https://website.com');return false;" class="link">Book NOW</a> </h2>
```

Comment: Try to change `onclick` attribute, containing code in string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
frameElement.href= "https://webite.com" + "?utm_campaign=" +paramId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer...

```js
//<![CDATA[
window.onload=function(){
url = document.location.href;
var paramId = new URL(url).searchParams.get("email");

var url = "iAmAttilasEvent(); Calendly.showPopupWidget('https://website.com" + "?utm_campaign=" +paramId + "');return false;";
document.getElementById("ID").setAttribute("onclick",url);


}//]]>
```

```html
   <a id="ID" href="" class="link">Book Now</a>
```